# How to remove whitespace from an asp:TextBox when using MaxLength property?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I've got an asp:TextBox which has a max length of 50, through the MaxLength property. The contents of this text box is written to a database.

The problem is that if the user does not fill in all 50 characters, the rest of the text box is filled with white space - thus also being saved into the database like so.

Is there any way to combat this?

Comment: Please post the code that saves the data to the database

Comment: Are you sure the TextBox adds whitespace? I'm fairly sure that the whitespace must be being added by the database. (You mean right-padding of spaces to fill up to 50 chars, right?)

Comment: @ANeves That's right, I'm suspecting it's the database.

Comment: you can try with txtbox.Text.Trim(); while reading the string, it removes white spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that you've declared your text column as `NCHAR(50)` or `CHAR(50)` rather than `NVARCHAR(50)` or `VARCHAR(50)`.

The former will write 50 characters to the table - padding out the input with spaces if necessary. The latter will write **up to** 50 characters to the table.

If you make this change then any new data will be written without trailing spaces, but any existing data will have to be cleaned up:

```
UPDATE table SET column = RTRIM(column) WHERE column LIKE '% '
```

Answer (score 2):

```
txtTextbox.Text = txtTextbox.Text.Trim();

// call to stored procedure follows
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting the value from the text box in the code behind use ".Trim()" on the string retrieved.  This will remove all preceding and trailing whitespace from the string.